# Word for lover of war, beginning with a B?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there is a word *beginning with the letter B* for someone who loves war and loves to conjure up support of war?

Comment: Are yiu thinking of "belligerent"?

Comment: "belligerent" can also be used as a noun, I hate to always suggest unusual usages of a word, but it's true. However, it does not meet your criteria exactly, because a "belligerent" is a person or country who is simply engaged in a war, not necessarily one who loves war itself.

Comment: I initially heard this as a setup for a joke - the answer being **Bush**

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for **[bellicose](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bellicose?q=bellicose)**.

> bellicose
>   (adjective) 
>   demonstrating aggression and willingness to fight:
>   *a mood of bellicose jingoism*

So: "a bellicose person".

As well, you could use the noun form , "bellicosity", to refer to a person's disposition.

> His **bellicosity** always led him into conflicts with his neighbors.

NB: There is no agent form of bellicose, nor usage of the adjective as noun (see: He's a *belligerent*, don't listen to him.)

Comment: +1. But perhaps you could be clearer that, unlike *belligerent*, this cannot be a noun.

Answer (score 5):

"Belligerent" is not a bad choice. I've heard it used to describe people who like to fight and/or engage in war. However, that usage is kind of a stretch. It really only means "engaged in war" (whether you like it or not).

A better choice would be "**warmonger**," which refers to a person who "encourages warfare" (which is closer to the "lover of war" that you asked about).

I hope this helps :)